# Yii framework - controller actions

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to create sample project in yii but I am having this problem while trying to run my code:

```
CHttpException

The system is unable to find the requested action "error". (C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CController.php:484)

#0 C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CController.php(271): CController->missingAction('error')
#1 C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(276): CController->run('error')
#2 C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(310): CWebApplication->runController('site/error')
#3 C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(183): CErrorHandler->render('error', Array)
#4 C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(108): CErrorHandler->handleException(Object(CHttpException))
#5 C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php(713): CErrorHandler->handle(Object(CExceptionEvent))
#6 [internal function]: CApplication->handleException(Object(CHttpException))
#7 {main}
```

Can anyone tell me the reason ? As I think this is not the problem of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exception has occurred (most likely due to a bug or misconfiguration) and Yii attempted to run the [error handler](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error#handling-errors-using-an-action), which in this case is the `error` action on the `site` controller.

The error occurs because you do not have a `site` controller, or it does not have an `error` action.

Comment: I have SiteControler but It doesnot have error action. How can I add Error action to SiteController Please tell me as I am newbie to yii

Comment: @ShumailaKhan: The [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#action) can help you.